# Displaying pilcrow signs at end of lines in LyX

Tags: lyx

I am a total noob in LyX and my friend using it is probably not much better, so we often have problems in that lines are broken where they shouldn't. The problem is usually caused by an end of line character in a wrong place. I would like to show these characters as pilcrow signs (¶) or something like that, as is possible in Word. Is that possible in LyX?

Comment: You see that you ended a line in LyX either by the indentation of the next line, or if you had a line break (with Ctrl+Enter) with the little red arrow at the end. If there is neither, there is no end of line in the output.

Comment: Note that when you hit enter in LyX you get a paragraph break, not a line break. Hard line breaks (```\\```), added with Ctrl + enter, are by default indicated with a down-left arrow as in [this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/tdbpcyO.png) (where I also activated the option scottkosty mentioned).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. so hitting enter matches… `\par`?

Comment: At least in normal text, yes. You can see from the code-panel in my screenshot that an empty line is inserted. I do not know for certain if LyX does something else in other environments, but you can always look at the sourcecode to see what it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Tools > Preferences (Ubuntu, Windows) or LyX > Preferences (Mac) and then go to "Display" on the left-hand tree, which is under Look & Feel. Then click the box "Mark end of paragraphs".

Comment: Would you think it appropriate to add in the Italian names of the menus for users of Italian LyX, or more in general any known foreign language version of those names? PS I don't have the Italian names yet, but soon I'll have my friend test your solution and tell me those names.

Comment: [This is the Preferences panel](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NL7kh.jpg), and going under "Visualizzazione" (=Display? What a translation…) you find [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8trAu.jpg), which has the required checkbox. Oh and to end the procedure you must click «Applica» (=Apply). Accepting answer.

Comment: @MickG Thank you for adding the Italian names. I don't understand what you mean by "any known foreign language version of those names"? How can we generalize the instructions in the answer so that they work for any language?

Comment: @MickG are you suggesting that the translation "Visualizzazione" could be improved? If so, LyX is always welcoming to volunteers who want to help improve the translations! Please send an email to lyx-docs@lists.lyx.org.

Comment: Reply to first comment: I was suggesting that if anyone knows the equivalents of these instructions in another language they could comment and we could edit the info into the answer. Second comment: I just find it strange to translate Display at all, seen as Display is a pretty well-known word in Italian. Just my opinion though...

Comment: @MickG ah I see what you mean. If you have any feedback on the translations, please do send in the suggestions so we can discuss them and improve things.